# Vaadin-Charts won´t apply all CSS styles on export/download

Tags: css, highcharts, vaadin, vaadin14, vaadin-charts

We have a few Vaadin charts (Pro) on our dashboard, which have been styled via CSS (font color, font size, bar colors,...). These CSS files are not on the system, but are loaded from an external server using @Stylesheet([URL]) in my Java-Class. The charts are built with Java. Everything is displayed correctly, but when using the built-in export function via the interface, not all styles are used. We are using Vaadin14. Does anyone here have an idea/solution?
[This is how it looks on our dashboard][1]
[This is how the downloaded chart looks like][2]
[This is the contextmenu][3]
As you can see, among other things, the bar colors and the font size are not applied correctly.

```
:host(.ChartDatenschutz) .highcharts-color-0, :host(.ChartDatenschutzTOM) .highcharts-color-0 {
  stroke: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-00);
                fill: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-00);
}

:host(.ChartDatenschutz) .highcharts-data-label-color-0 text, :host(.ChartDatenschutzTOM) .highcharts-data-label-color-0 text {
  fill:var(---kl-red-color);
                font-weight: 600;
}

:host(.ChartDatenschutz) .highcharts-color-1, :host(.ChartDatenschutzTOM) .highcharts-color-1 {
  stroke: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-01);
                fill: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-01);
}

:host(.ChartDatenschutz) .highcharts-color-2, :host(.ChartDatenschutzTOM) .highcharts-color-2 {
  stroke: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-02);
                fill: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-02);
}

:host(.ChartDatenschutz) .highcharts-color-3, :host(.ChartDatenschutzTOM) .highcharts-color-3 {
  stroke: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-03);
                fill: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-03);
}

:host(.ChartDatenschutz) .highcharts-color-4, :host(.ChartDatenschutzTOM) .highcharts-color-4 {
  stroke: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-04);
                fill: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-04);
}

:host(.ChartDatenschutz) .highcharts-color-5, :host(.ChartDatenschutzTOM) .highcharts-color-5 {
  stroke: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-05);
                fill: var(---kl-highcharts-fortschritt-color-05);
}

:host(.ChartDatenschutz) .highcharts-data-label-color-5 text, :host(.ChartDatenschutzTOM) .highcharts-data-label-color-5 text {
  fill: var(---kl-white-color);
}

:host(.ChartDatenschutz) .highcharts-legend-item, :host(.ChartDatenschutzTOM) .highcharts-legend-item {
  fill: var(---kl-text-color);
}
```

(Part of the CSS)
The styles come from an external design team, which means I don't have direct access to the files. However, I can let them know if something needs to be changed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you try using `chart.styledMode`, it's default style sheet is available from https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css? Let me know if is loading full or partial.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I set the styledMode in Vaadin 14? I don't see a method for it. I see this method only in Vaadin 23

Comment: Sorry, I can help you only with HC configuration, I don't know Vaadin.

Comment: The official way of exporting Vaadin Charts was added in V21 and does not support styling with CSS. It has to be done from the Java API. See the docs for more information https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/charts/svg-generator/#customizing-svg-generation

Comment: @Knoobie can you formulate answer from this, what you say is correct.

Answer (score 0):

CSS styling of exported charts is not supported in Vaadin 23.0: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/charts/svg-generator/#customizing-svg-generation

> CSS styling is not supported when exporting a chart as SVG.